# Parsing large XML file in R is very slow

Tags: xml, r, performance, xml-parsing, dataframe

I need to extract data from a large xml file in R. The file size is 60 MB. I use the following R code to download the data from the Internet:

```
library(XML)
library(httr)

url = "http://hydro1.sci.gsfc.nasa.gov/daac-bin/his/1.0/NLDAS_NOAH_002.cgi"
SOAPAction = "http://www.cuahsi.org/his/1.0/ws/GetSites"
envelope = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n<soap:Body>\n<GetSites xmlns=\"http://www.cuahsi.org/his/1.0/ws/\">\n<site></site><authToken></authToken>\n</GetSites>\n</soap:Body>\n</soap:Envelope>"

response = POST(url, body = envelope,
             add_headers("Content-Type" = "text/xml", "SOAPAction" = SOAPAction))
status.code = http_status(response)$category
```

Once I have received the response from the server, I use the following code to parse the data into a data.frame:

```
# Parse the XML into a tree
WaterML = content(response, as="text")
SOAPdoc = xmlRoot(xmlTreeParse(WaterML, getDTD=FALSE, useInternalNodes = TRUE))
doc = SOAPdoc[[1]][[1]][[1]]

# Allocate a new empty data frame with same name of rows as the number of sites
N = xmlSize(doc) - 1
df = data.frame(SiteName=rep("",N),
             SiteID=rep(NA, N),
             SiteCode=rep("",N),
             Latitude=rep(NA,N),
             Longitude=rep(NA,N),
             stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# Populate the data frame with the values
# This loop is VERY SLOW it takes around 10 MINUTES!
start.time = Sys.time()

for(i in 1:N){  
  siteInfo = doc[[i+1]][[1]]
  siteList = xmlToList(siteInfo)
  siteName = siteList$siteName
  sCode = siteList$siteCode
  siteCode = sCode$text
  siteID = ifelse(is.null(sCode$.attrs["siteID"]), siteCode,   sCode$.attrs["siteID"])
  latitude = as.numeric(siteList$geoLocation$geogLocation$latitude)
  longitude = as.numeric(siteList$geoLocation$geogLocation$longitude) 
}

end.time = Sys.time()
time.taken = end.time - start.time
time.taken
```

The for loop that I use to parse the XML into a data.frame is very slow. It takes around 10 minutes to complete. Is there any way to make the loop faster?

Comment: This is a very large XML dataset, so it's not surprising that it takes quite some time to parse using the XML-specific libraries.  If the data are extremely structured then you can easily write your own looping structure along with some regular expressions to parse the data.  But it seems like this is a one-time problem so 10 minutes seems a decent trade-off for a solution that would likely take longer than 10 minutes to solve?

Comment: For me this is not a one-time problem because the online XML dataset is being updated every day. So I need to make the parsing as fast as possible.

Comment: Is the bottleneck in calling xmlToList so many times (what's a typical value of N?)? Could you convert the whole xmldoc to a list once and work with that? 60Mb isn't really "large" (it should fit in RAM) so I'd expect it to be possible and that might be faster.

Comment: Also, your code doesn't actually change `df` in the loop, so its not populating the data frame! Write it as a function with `N` as a parameter so you can test it on fewer rows in order to not have to wait 20 minutes to see if your code works.

Comment: You don't need to do the `xmlToList` conversion in order to extract the elements. Try accessing the nodes by name, eg: `doc[[123]][[1]][["geoLocation"]][["geogLocation"]][["latitude"]][["text"]]` gets you the latitude. Or by number if you are confident the format is constant (eg: `doc[[123]][[1]][[3]][[1]][[1]][["text"]]`. Also, do conversions to numeric at the end on the whole data frame column (`df$latitude = as.numeric(df$latitude)`).

Comment: Good suggestions. Converting the whole xmldoc to a list once took around 6 minutes so there was some speed improvement. Accessing the nodes by name instead of using xmlToList improved the speed for N < 50,000, but strangely it made the parsing slower for N > 100,000. The solution with xpathSApply from Joshua Ulrich appears to give the best performance especially for very big xml data with N > 100,000 and size > 50 MB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get better performance by using xpath expressions to extract the information you want. Each of the calls to `xpathSApply` takes ~20 seconds on my laptop, so all the commands complete in less than 2 minutes.

```
# you need to specify the namespace information
ns <- c(soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",
        xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema",
        xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance",
        sr="http://www.cuahsi.org/waterML/1.0/",
        gsr="http://www.cuahsi.org/his/1.0/ws/")

Data <- list(
  siteName = xpathSApply(SOAPdoc, "//sr:siteName", xmlValue, namespaces=ns),
  siteCode = xpathSApply(SOAPdoc, "//sr:siteCode", xmlValue, namespaces=ns),
  siteID = xpathSApply(SOAPdoc, "//sr:siteCode", xmlGetAttr, name="siteID", namespaces=ns),
  latitude = xpathSApply(SOAPdoc, "//sr:latitude", xmlValue, namespaces=ns),
  longitude = xpathSApply(SOAPdoc, "//sr:longitude", xmlValue, namespaces=ns))
DataFrame <- as.data.frame(Data, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
DataFrame$latitude <- as.numeric(DataFrame$latitude)
DataFrame$longitude <- as.numeric(DataFrame$longitude)
```

Comment: Very good solution, it took ~2 minutes on my laptop to complete. And thank you for the example how to use xpathSApply. I suspected that the "xpath" functions would be faster, but I couldn't figure out how to correctly specify the namespace information. Your answer is a great example how to use xpath in R to parse an XML document with lots of namespaces.